# Problems creating and getting values from multidimensional vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I am having problems creating and getting values from a multidimensional array in C++. I have spent quite some time trying to figure out why this is not compiling. What's wrong here?

The code is as follows;

`vector<vector<string>> vec;
vec[0][0] = "asd";
cout << vec[0][0] << endl;`

Comment: you mind adding the compile-error?

Comment: You need to `resize` or `push_back`. If you `resize` you can `[]` index; otherwise, `push_back("asd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not assign a value to an empty vector using the subscript operator.

You could use methods like `emplace_back` or `push_back` or `insert`

For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;

vec.emplace_back( 1, "asd" );
vec.push_back( { 1, "fgh" } );
vec.insert( vec.end(), { 1, "jkl" } );

std::cout << vec[0][0] << std::endl;
std::cout << vec[1][0] << std::endl;
std::cout << vec[2][0] << std::endl;
```

Or you could initially create the vector with the required number of elements. And in this case you may use the subscript operator.

For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec( 1, std::vector<std::string>( 1 ) );

vec[0][0] = "asd";

std::cout << vec[0][0] << std::endl;
```

There are many ways to do the task. For example you could use the following approach

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;
vec.resize( 1 );
vec[0].resize( 1 );

vec[0][0] = "asd";

std::cout << vec[0][0] << std::endl;
```

Comment: g++ will give an error for `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;`. Try `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vec;` instead (notice the space between the angle-brackets).

Comment: OP said "this is not compiling"...?

Comment: @dingalapadum It should be fine since c++11.

Comment: @dingalapadum Thank you! that actually helps clear some things up for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this really helped

Comment: @songyuanyao : Oh, thx, didn't know that! Anyway, judging from OPs comment he actually isn't using c++11........ that's why it would have been good, if he had included the actual error-message.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation of the constructor. When you do this:

```
vector<string> vec;
vec[0] = "asd";
cout << vec[0] << endl;
```

You have UB twice, because you are trying to access an element in the vector, that does not exist. The first line just creates an empty vector. You either want to push new elements:

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.push_back("asd");
cout << vec[0] << endl;
```

or pass the size to the constructor:

```
size_t start_size=10;
vector<string> vec(start_size);
vec[0] = "asd";
cout << vec[0] << endl;
```

For 2D this would be:

```
typedef vector<vector<string>> MAT;
MAT mat;
vector<string> vec;
vec.push_back("asd");
mat.push_back(vec);
cout << mat[0][0] << endl;
```

or:

```
size_t start_size=10;
MAT mat = MAT(start_size,vector<string>(start_size));
mat[0][0] = "asd";
cout << mat[0][0] << endl;
```

However, using a `vector<vector<T>>` is in general not advisable.